Installing Ubuntu on an x86 Android tablet (Lenovo Yoga tablet 2)
Yes, as the title suggests, TWRP is in Teamwin recovery project.
I dug out my old x86 tablet (a Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2) the other day and wondered if Ubuntu could be installed on it. It has 16GB of SSD and an  Intel Atom (baytrail?) Z3745 processor.
While trying to install Ubuntu on it I was lucky and got hold of the Windows version of the same tablet in a yard sale which has a different UEFI system but I managed to install Ubuntu 20 LTS x64 with a custom bootloader that boots on 32-bit UEFI. All other configurations are default.
Getting into the UEFI to USB install on the Android version is more difficult, as the device does not recognize any external devices until a Kernel is loaded. But the lure of a modern Ubuntu is too strong (XD), especially since the only differences between the devices are touch-capable UEFI for the Windows version and 32GB SSD. Other specs are the same.
Now, I managed to root my Android version of the tablet and install TWRP on it. I followed a (badly translated) tutorial from 4pda and got into the UEFI.
The problem is, that the device does not recognize any external devices until a Kernel is loaded, so I would have to copy the installed Ubuntu from the Windows version of the tablet (Ubuntu is around 10GB in size) to the Android tablet, and then find the file that makes this Ubuntu system boot and boot from the UEFI menu.
I also tried using the terminal from TWRP, however, fdisk seems to be broken as no partitions are listed. (or maybe it is a GPT system as it boots from UEFI? But no GPT variants are in the options listed in the /Sbin)
I now want to try to install TWRP on my Windows machine, make a clone, and then restore (install) Ubuntu (and update, maybe) on the tablet. No tutorials are available as I am concerned.
Any suggestions or ideas? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

it's possible, but you will probably be the first one. The entire android community is all about quick hacks. So all results for linux on x86 tablets will result in people just installing chroot linux apps and using android vnc client full screen. Good luck.
